# Conditionally delete xml tags

Tags: search

In a file containing tags like these:

```
<div class="myclass">
Something irrelevant.
</div>
<div class="myclass">
MATCH ME
</div>
```

I would like to delete all tags *not* containing a specific pattern, here "MATCH ME" as an example. I can search for the opening of the tag, then do `vat`, inspect the selection, if it doesn't contain my pattern I hit `d` to delete it and move on to the next candidate with `n`, else I will hit `n` straight, continuing to the end of the file. Now I'd like to automate that, as I have a few files like that. How?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `MATCH ME` is always a single line, you can use something like:

```
:g/^MATCH ME/-1,+1d
```

- First, `:g/^MATCH ME/` will search for all instances of `MATCH ME`.
- We then run the `:d` (`:delete`) command on everything that matches with `:g`, but we also add a range of `-1,+1`, meaning one line before and one line after the matched line.

If your `MATCH ME` pattern may consist of multiple lines, we need a slightly more advanced version:

```
:g/^MATCH ME/call DeleteBetween('<div class="myclass">', '<\/div>')
```

Instead of adding a whole bunch on the command-line (which quickly becomes unreadable), I created a little helper function:

```
fun! DeleteBetween(start, end)
    " Reverse search for where we should start deleting
    execute '?' . a:start

    " Remember the line number
    let l:start = line('.')

    " Forward search for when we should stop deleting
    execute '/' . a:end

    " And delete the line range (:4,8d)
    execute ':' . l:start . ',' . line('.') . 'd'
endfun
```